# How to send messages to myself on WhatsApp

Tags: whatsapp

I was able to send myself messages via WhatsApp

I did this by Open any browser (Google Chrome, Firefox) on your phone or PC and typing wa.me// in the address bar, followed by my phone number

This has been working great and continues to work from my Android phone. It also works perfectly from the web client, https://web.whatsapp.com/

If I try to send myself a message via the Desktop app (downloaded from Windows Store, using Windows 11) I get the following message:

[image]

I don't see anything I need to confirm within my phone

How do I get the desktop app working

[image]

The box where I would normally write messages now shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just create a new group with friend, then kick that friend, and keep talking with yourself. Will that work?

Edit: You should try WhatsApp Beta... I never had a such problem.
https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBDXK71NK08

Comment: https://techwelkin.com/whatsapp-send-message-to-yourself

Comment: @Toto, the essential part is in the answer. Did you read it?

Answer (score 1):

This method works on the phone, but needs to be verified for the
desktop app:

- Open WhatsApp on your the Chats tab
- Tap the "new chat" icon
- At the top of the list of contacts, you will see your name
  with the text "Message yourself" under it
- Select your own contact to open the new chat
- A chat window will open just like a regular chat
- Here you can type and send messages to yourself.

Comment: When I follow these steps, I see the `WhatsApp's terms and privacy policy update` image I shared in my original post

Comment: If the message is to be trusted, you need to do it once on the phone, in order to accept the terms.

Comment: When I attempt this on my phone, as per my post, it just works - there is no prompt to accept any T&Cs. I message my self without issue

Comment: Seems like a bug in the desktop version. I would suggest to contact Support.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the WhatsApp Desktop app on Windows 11 may not support sending messages to yourself.
The browser method is effective, so continue using it on your Android phone or PC.